# How can I run yarn dev from a Next.js project inside of my Swift project?

Tags: macos, shell, embedded-resource

In the Copy Files Build Phase, I've a directory with a Next.js project to be "copied only when installing" to the "Resources" destination. I also have a `Resources` folder with the `web` project directory in it

In my AppDelegate, I'm loading the directory but am unclear on how to run `yarn dev` in/on it.

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "web", withExtension: nil) {
  let process = Process()

  // Unsure what to do here to run `yarn dev` and start my local server. 

  do {
     try process.run()
  }

  catch {
     print("some error occurred")
     print("")
  }
}
```

How can I get this working properly?

Thanks!

**Edit**

It's a brand new project, so I'm just using the `index.js` file inside of the `web` project at this point. Normally in Terminal I'd just `cd` into `web` and run `yarn dev` to start a server at `localhost:3000`, so that's essentially what I'm trying to do here. Thanks

Here is the contents of the `Resources/web` folder:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have placed the shell script in the Resources folder of the main app and you are running macOS 10.13 or later, please use this code:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "run_server", withExtension: "sh") {
     guard let resourcesURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL else { return }
     let webURL = resourcesURL.appendingPathComponent("web")
     let process = Process()
     process.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
     process.arguments = [url.path, webURL.path]
     
     do {
         try process.run()
     }

     catch {
         // handle any errors here
     }
}
```

Concerning your script, I'd use something like this:

```
#!bin/bash

cd $1
yarn dev -p 3000
```

$1 will be set to the path passed as the second argument to the `process` that will run your shell.

Comment: Thanks jvarela. I just created a Resources folder in in the app and moved the next.js app and the bash script into it. `url` is successfully set but `script` returns nil. My bash script does the following `#!/bin/bash

cd './web'
yarn dev -p 3000`

And I get the error `"Expected end of line, etc. but found unknown token.";`

Comment: I don't think you can use cd "./web" in your script unless you set up the current working directory properly. Please explain exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Will give this a try now. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I hope you are not putting all those commands in the same line either, or that will give an error. If you want to put them on the same line you need to concatenate them with &&.

Comment: Okay, getting somewhere! So I'm in the bash script, I'm able to `echo "hello world" but it's trying to run `cd "./web"` tells me "no such file or directory". Doing an `ls` just shows `MyProject.app` and `MyProject.swiftmodule`. I can load the "web" directory in the same way, using `Bundle.main.url` but I guess I'm not sure what to do next

Comment: They're on subsequent lines, that's just how the SO comment formatted it but good lookin out!

Comment: @Zack Shapiro You really cannot use cd './web' in your script. Your working directory must be set properly first before you can use '.' in your scripts.

Comment: I've updated the original question now that I have a bit of a better context thanks to your help so far

Comment: Your question still lacks important information. You need to explain what exactly the structure of the web folder is and what you are trying to run with yarn that is inside this folder. Without this, I'm unable to help.

Comment: I've just added a screenshot of the `Resources/web` folder and subdirectories. It's a brand new project, so I'm just using the `index.js` file at this point. Normally in terminal I'd just `cd` into that directory and run `yarn dev` to start a server at `localhost:3000`, so that's essentially what I'm trying to do here. Thanks

Comment: FWIW `yarn dev` is an alias from `package.json` for the `next dev` command

Comment: Just wanted to bump this, I'd love to get it working today if possible. Thanks so much for your help so far, @jvarela!